# Meaning of “Dis donc” in a certain context

Tags: expressions, oral, interjections

I've heard million times, someone responds "bah dis donc" when the other guy tells something to him. And it happens to me sometimes. I told a story, then the guy I talked with respond "bah dis donc".

So, what is the meaning of "dis donc" in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the context, it can express surprise or admiration, or ironically the opposite of that. If you want an English traduction, you can imagine the other person is saying "wow", "you don't say", "geez", or something like that.

> - [...] et quand j'ai mis une droite à l'ours, il s'est enfui !
> - Bah dis donc !

could become:

> - [...] and when I punched the bear, it ran away!
> - Wow!

Since it's a rather versatile expression mostly used orally, it's rather hard to be more specific without more precise context, intonation...

Comment: *Bah dis donc* for *You don't say* only if it's ironic, I suppose.

Comment: @simondéchamps yes, I think this fits the context, thanks!